# Multiple validation errors with INotifyDataErrorInfo, old messages don't disappear

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

In a WPF project, I'm validating a TextBox input with an INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation. Multiple errors can occur.

When I input something that causes multiple errors, all validation errors are displayed. However, when I fix one error, the validation message doesn't change, that means that false error messages are shown. Only when I fix all errors the message disappears.

Is that a problem with my implementation, or does the WPF implementation only re-fetch the validation message if HasErrors changed? Stepping through it with a debugger, however, I can see that GetErrors and HasErrors both are called.

Steps to reproduce with attached example:

- Enter 333333. 2 validation messages are shown.
- Change the leading 3 to a 2. Still, both validation messages are shown, although the first error has been fixed.
- Change the second 3 to a 0. Both messages disappear
- Change the second digit to a 3 again. The second validation message is shown.
- change the leading digit to a 3 again. Only the second validation message is shown, although it should display both.

And yes, the example doesn't make much sense, since I could actually get rid of the first check, since it's included in the second check.

The view:

```
<Window x:Class="WeirdValidationTest.ValidationTestView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WeirdValidationTest"
        Height="60" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ValidationTestViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ValidationErrorsToStringConverter x:Key="ValErrToString" />
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValErrToString}}" Background="White" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox MaxLength="6" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}"
                 Text="{Binding InputValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(Code-behind is simple InitializeComponent call in constructor)

The ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WeirdValidationTest
{
    internal class ValidationTestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        private uint inputValue;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

        public uint InputValue
        {
            get
            {
                return inputValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (inputValue != value)
                {
                    if (value / 100000 == 2)
                    {
                        RemoveError("InputValue",
                                    String.Format("Must be in range {0}...{1}", "200000", "299999"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddError("InputValue",
                                 String.Format("Must be in range {0}...{1}", "200000", "299999"));
                    }

                    uint testNumber = (uint) ((value) / 1e4);

                    {
                        string msg = string.Format("Must start with value {0}", "20....");
                        if (testNumber != 20)
                        {
                            AddError("InputValue", msg);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            RemoveError("InputValue", msg);
                        }
                    }

                    inputValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get
            {
                return errors.Count != 0;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            List<string> val;
            errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out val);
            return val;
        }

        void AddError(string propertyName, string messageText)
        {
            List<string> errList;
            if (errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out errList))
            {
                if (!errList.Contains(messageText))
                {
                    errList.Add(messageText);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errList = new List<string> { messageText };
                errors.Add(propertyName, errList);
            }
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }

        void RemoveError(string propertyName, string messageText)
        {
            List<string> errList;
            if (errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out errList))
            {
                errList.Remove(messageText);
                if (errList.Count == 0)
                {
                    errors.Remove(propertyName);
                }
            }
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }

        private void OnErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = ErrorsChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WeirdValidationTest
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>), typeof(string))]
    internal class ValidationErrorsToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
           var errorCollection = value as ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>;

            if (errorCollection == null)
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            return String.Join(", ", errorCollection.Select(e => e.ErrorContent.ToString()));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                  CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Target .net version is 4.5

edit:
Hit a similar problem with `IDataErrorInfo`, see this question:
[Validation Rule not updating correctly with 2 validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984270/validation-rule-not-updating-correctly-with-2-validation-rules)
Changing the converter helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice explanation and your code looks pretty good too. I resolved your issue in my way hope you like it.
Just change your AddError and RemoveError methods like this,

```
void AddError(string propertyName, string messageText)
        {
            List<string> errList;
            if (errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out errList))
            {
                if (!errList.Contains(messageText))
                {
                    errList.Add(messageText);
                    errors.Remove(propertyName);
                    OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
                    if (errList != null)
                        errors.Add(propertyName, errList);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                errList = new List<string> { messageText };
                errors.Add(propertyName, errList);
                OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
            }
        }
        void RemoveError(string propertyName, string messageText)
        {
            List<string> errList;
            if (errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out errList))
            {
                errList.Remove(messageText);
                errors.Remove(propertyName);
            }
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
            if (errList != null)
                errors.Add(propertyName, errList);

        }
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks. Just 2 questions: Why isn't there a final OnErrorsChanged in both methods (Works without, but I would actually guess that it's needed)? And what's the point of the errList != null check that late in the method (It should be rather at the beginning of the method, I guess, I just forgot it in my example)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, because after all this time I found the culprit.

The main problem is my ErrorTemplate. `Validation.Errors` being bound to a TextBox in the ErrorTemplate. See also [Binding ObservableCollection<> to a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4353186/3872702).
Since `Validation.Errors` is a `ObservableCollecton`, it doesn't fire the `PropertyChanged` event. This, the binding (the error template) doesn't get updated.