# WPF does not update error message when validating with IDataErrorInfo and custom error template uisng a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

This question is related to [Validation Rule not updating correctly with 2 validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14984270/3872702), but I'm not using ValidationRule, but the IDataErrorInfo interface.

Consider the following example, where the user has to select either option with a RadioButton, the validation then depends on the selection.
If Option 1 is selected, the entered string must begin with A, if option 2 is selected, it must begin with B.

If the user changes the option, the TextBox must be re-validated. As the answer provided in the linked question, using CurrentItem.ErrorContent in the error template does work, in that the error message is updated. (I only use CurrentItem.ErrorContent, (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent displays nothing, but that's another issue I guess).

To reproduce, select option 1 and type in anything that doesn't start with A or B (e.g. VVVVV). Now select option 2.
The error message binding using the custom converter (displaying all error messages) still says that the string must begin with A, while the other binding in the error template correctly states that the string must begin with B.

Accoding to the answer provided there, this is because the ValidationRule prevents the actual property bound to to be updated, thus a NotifyPropertyChanged won't do anything. Here, however, the property is updated.

Is there a reason WPF doesn't call the converter again (bug or feature)?
Is there some way I can force the converter being called again, thus updating the first error message?

ValidationDemo.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ValidationIssue2.ValidationDemo"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:validationIssue2="clr-namespace:ValidationIssue2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <validationIssue2:ValidationViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <validationIssue2:ValidationErrorsToStringConverter x:Key="ValErrToString" />
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValErrToString}}" Background="White" />
                    <Label> / </Label>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" Background="White" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Option1}">Option 1</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Option2}">Option 2</RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Text="{Binding ValidateThis, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ValidationDemo.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ValidationIssue2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ValidationDemo : Window
    {
        public ValidationDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ValidationErrorsToStringConverter.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ValidationIssue2
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>), typeof(string))]
    internal class ValidationErrorsToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
           var errorCollection = value as ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>;

            if (errorCollection == null)
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            return String.Join(", ", errorCollection.Select(e => e.ErrorContent.ToString()));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                  CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

ValidationViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ValidationIssue2
{
    class ValidationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private bool option1;

        private bool option2;
        private string validateThis;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool Option1
        {
            get
            {
                return option1;
            }
            set
            {
                option1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                // since this does influece text validation
                OnPropertyChanged("");
            }
        }

        public bool Option2
        {
            get
            {
                return option2;
            }
            set
            {
                option2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                // since this does influece text validation
                OnPropertyChanged("");
            }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get { return String.Empty; }
        }

        public string ValidateThis
        {
            get
            {
                return validateThis;
            }
            set
            {
                validateThis = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (columnName)
                {
                    case "ValidateThis":
                        if (Option1)
                        {
                            return ValidateThis.StartsWith("A") ? String.Empty : "Must start with A";
                        }
                        if (Option2)
                        {
                            return ValidateThis.StartsWith("B") ? String.Empty : "Must start with B";
                        }
                        return String.Empty;
                    default:
                        return String.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your `OnPropertyChanged("")`s on the 'Option' bools to `OnPropertyChanged("ValidateThis")`

Comment: @Blinx I did, but that doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect it's due to the value of `ValidateThis` not changing. This would mean (I'm pretty sure) that the UI doesn't 'think' it needs to update. You could possibly try setting `ValidateThis` to another value and then back to it's original value whenever one of the options are set and make sure to notify inbetween